# How to put value of day of month in my code

Tags: java, html, jsp

How to store string variable in date object? I am getting this error:

> An error occurred at line: 25 in the jsp file: /date.jsp formatter cannot be resolved

```
 <%
    try
     {
       Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
       date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
       Date date1;
       DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       String str=df.format(date.getTime());
       //out.println(str); this is showing date formate 01/03/2014 
       date1 = (Date)df.parse(str); 
       out.println(date1); //but this is showing as "Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 IST 2014" but i want to show like that 01/03/2014
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
 %>
```

Comment: formatter variable is not declared... I think you were trying to use Dateformat object df. Replace formatter with df. Also you might need to surround the line with a try catch statement that handles ParseException

Comment: I don't understand that you are trying to do : are you parsing a String as a Date, or are you parsing a Date as a String ? For what purpose ?

Comment: i am parsing a String  as a date

Comment: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date1 = df.parse("1/01/2014"); //here i want to put date from calendar instead of manually 
        Date date13 = new Date();Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal1.setTime(date3);
        cal2.setTime(date13);

Comment: If you want to parse a String as a Date, it's already done : `date1 = (Date)df.parse(str);`. As for why `out.println(date1)` don't give you `01/03/2014`, it's because `date1` is a Date, and so `println` call the `toString` function from `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the date, build a string using `java.util.Calendar`'s .get() method.

```
String dateStr = date.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + (date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/" + date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
out.print(dateStr);
```

And put them in whatever order you want them in.  If you need time element, look at the documentation for `java.util.Calendar` to see what other elements can be used as the parameter to the .get() method.

Answer (score 0):

## Confusing Question

Are you simply trying to get the first day of the month of the current date-time?

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library makes date-time work much easier than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now().withZone( timeZone );
DateTime firstOfMonth = now.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```